# Dynamically create html action links using javascript variables on ASP.NET MVC3 razor

Tags: javascript, html, razor, actionlink

Say I have a javascript dictionary variable with the following key value pairs:

```
var attributes = { name : "name1", age: 10}
```

I want to use the values in the above attribute to create the children of an HTML ul element within the same javascript function as follows:

```
var htmlContent = '<ul><li>@Html.ActionLink(attributes["name"], "Details", "Home", new { name = attributes["name"]})</li></ul>'
```

Is there a way to do this?  TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you can use the JavaScript `attributes` variable in the `@Html.ActionLink`?

I'd recommend changing it to

```
var htmlContent = '<ul><li><a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Home")" name="' +
    attributes.name + '">Link</a></li></ul>';
```