# Modify Razor params within Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, razor

I am trying to modify parameters routeValue in Razor within Javascript.

```
function setForm(param) {
   var formCariEntitas = '@Html.Action("FormCariEntitas", "Registrasi", New With {.id = "entitas"'+param+'})';
   return formCariEntitas; 
}
```

But the error said, "param is not declared. It may be inaccessible". Is there any other way? Is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. Razor is server side, your JavaScript is clientside.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
   var formCariEntitas ='@Url.Action("FormCariEntitas", "Registrasi")?parameter=' + param;
```

Comment: Its not possible. He's mixing ClientSide and ServerSide.

Comment: No actually I have done it in one of my project using above code. The only thing is we need to pass data as querystring

Comment: I am using @Html.Action to get the view. Your code is work if I give .get in return:
`return $.get(formCariEntitas, function (data) {
            $('#some_id').html(data);
        });`

Comment: then i think @Phill is right :) check this link might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525702/dynamically-create-html-action-links-using-javascript-variables-on-asp-net-mvc3